# PUT custom find update REST API Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I have created a basic REST api in Node js and Mongodb. I want to update the value using Find with Custom Parameter such as `name`. I am able to get the user using Custom GET method but it it not working in PUT/POST Method.

Here is the Schema:

```
{
    name:String,
    value:Number
}
```

Here is the code:

//v1/api/users/:name -Update

```
api.put('/users/:name',(req,res)=>{
Users.find({name:req.params.name},(err,user)=>{
if(err){

  res.send(err);
}
console.log(req.body.name);
console.log(req.body.value);


user.value= req.body.value;
user.save(err => {
  if(err){

    res.send(err);
  }
  res.json({message:'Updated '});

   });


   });
 });
```

Now for example if the `mongoDb` has `"name":"sam"` and I use `localhost:3000/v1/api/users/sam`` and body as

1.`{"value":300}`, I get error

> Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

2.When I logged the 1st error, I came to know that not defining the name was giving me the error. so I used this `{"name":"sam","value":300}` and now the error is user. save is not a function.

Updating using `FindById` is working,but in client case,the user cannot get the id from the database, so I tried the above method.

Please Help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the error is user.save is not a function.

This is because `find()` returns a `[]` of matching documents.

As per [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html),

> findOne() it is a potentially-null single document, find() a list of documents,

Even if there is only document with `{"name":"sam"}`, you'll get as `[{"name":"sam"}]`. `save()` is being called on an array leading to the error.

```
'use strict';

api.put('/users/:name', (req, res) => {
  Users.findOne({
    name: req.params.name
  }, (err, user) => {

    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }

    if (user === null) {
      return res.send({
        msg: 'No matching user with name sam'
      });
    }

    console.log(req.body.name);
    console.log(req.body.value);

    user.value = req.body.value;
    user.save(err => {
      if (err) {

        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({message: 'Updated '});
    });

  });
});
```

You can also fix this by getting first element of the `find()` result, and then operating on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
api.put('/users/:name', (req, res) => {
    Users.find({
        name: req.params.name
    }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
            res.send({
                message: 'User not found'
            });
        }

        user.value = req.body.value;
        user.save(err => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Updated '
            });

        });

    });
});
```